# How to speed up object detection in tensor flow with python?

Tags: tensorflow, dataset, object-detection

I use tensor flow object detection to detect car number (Vehicle registration plate). After training my dataset, tensorflow detect 30 car number in 30 images in one minute, i.e., two second for each image. As you know, for highway with heavy car traffic, two second for each detection is too much time. My question is that how can I speed up object detection in tensorflow? should I use a more powerful GPU? Or I need to  train the detection with bigger dataset? Or I need to implement tensorflow on C++ instead of python? Or using special operation system?

Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does tensorflow give you warnings about GPU memory utilisation? And was the training phase slow as well (i.e. 0.5 samples per second during training)? Generally, inference is fast compared to training...

Comment: Yes. after training dataset, when i use the detector script, It gives some warnings about GPU memory allocation. Also, each train step take long 1.5 second. I use gforce 740m with compute capability 3.5 .

Comment: Memory warnings indicate that the network is too large to fit entirely on your GPU. See if the [tensorflow object detection tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb) works as expected.

Comment: @Farshad get in touch with me over skype : oziocan